# Flutter in app purchase for android app not getting test payment methods

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have implemented in app purchase in flutter for android and ios, but facing an issue in android side, while tested in ios its working, but not sure for testing in android device google play, as their documentations, i have submitted app to internal testing and as well as production too.

the issue is when ever i tried to test while i am a 'internal tester', not getting the test payment methods. i prompt with my real payment methods from google play. any suggestion/guide what i should have to do to test IAP.

i attached a screen shot as playstore is showing me as a internal tester.... but in app when try to purchase playstore show a real payment method, not test cards. btw i have multiple accounts signed in to my device, could this be the reason ?

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried using "android.test.purchased" as a product?

Answer (score 2):

Have you completed the following steps?

1. Go to **Google Play Console**.
2. Go to **Settings** (in Left Menu).
3. Go to **Developer Account** (and Account Details).
4. Scroll and go to section **License Testing**.
5. Add your **google account** there and save it.
6. Add the same **google account** as a tester on **internal testing** in Google Play Console.
7. Log in **Play Store** and **Google chrome** on your device with the same testing/google account you added above.
8. From **Internal Testing** of **Google Play Console** you will get a link, open that on your device browser (chrome) and accept invitation for testing.

If you have missed any of the step then complete it and test the app again!

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have completed all these steps, i attached screenshot too, as playstore indicating as internal tester, but when try to purchase play store shows real payment methods.

Comment: @SaifUrRehmanSaif Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @DinhQuangTuan yes it was solved, try to test on separate device, it occurs some time on device if multiple accounts are signed in... might be i am wrong but i used separate device with only account and it solved.

Comment: @Muhammad Usama Siddiqui, I am having the reverse issue, I cannot turn off my test mode to real mode. I am trying to do a closed testing here. Any idea how to resolve this?